# Objective-C disassembling - I dont understand this code

Tags: osx, nasm

I assembled a simple objective-c file that prints hello to the screen. this is the code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main() {
    NSString* a = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: "hi"];
    NSLog(a);
    return 0;
}
```

When I assembled it and converted it into Nasm syntax, this is the output:

```
section .text
default rel
extern _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSString
extern _NSLog
extern _objc_msgSend   
global _main 
_main:   
    push rbp 
    mov rbp, rsp 
    sub rsp, 16 
    lea rdx, [ L_.str] 
    mov dword [rbp - 4], 0
    mov rax, qword [ L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_] 
    mov rsi, qword [ L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_]
    mov rdi, rax 
    call    _objc_msgSend 
    mov qword [rbp - 16], rax 
    mov rax, qword [rbp - 16] 
    mov rdi, rax ; rdi has rax
    mov al, 0 
    call    _NSLog 
    xor eax, eax 
    add rsp, 16 
    pop rbp 
    ret 

segment __DATA,__objc_classrefs
L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_: dq  _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSString

    segment __TEXT,__cstring
L_.str: db  "hi"

    segment .__TEXT,.__objc_methname
L_OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_:   db "stringWithUTF8String:"

    segment __DATA,__objc_selrefs
L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_: dq L_OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_

    segment __DATA,__objc_imageinfo
L_OBJC_IMAGE_INFO:
    dd  0
    dd  64
```

I understand most of it, like the different objc segments, but I dont understand things like `mov   rax, qword [rbp - 16]` or even `mov al, 0`. This is 64 bit assembly code so why is the register `al` referenced? and why is `[rbp-16]` stored into `rax`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The instructions

```
mov qword [rbp - 16], rax 
mov rax, qword [rbp - 16]
```

are created by the compiler which is using [stack based memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation) to store the result from the NSString objc call. If you compile with optimizations, the compiler should eliminate the need to store the value in stack altogether.

The

```
mov al, 0
```

is set as an input to the NSLog function which is a variadic function so it needs a way to determine how many variables are stored in vector registers (`xmm`/`ymm`) vs general purpose ones (e.g. `rdi`, `rsi`, etc.) when processing the input arguments. Since the number of vector registers is far less than 256, it only needs to use 8-bits and will only look at `al`. This saves a bit of space in code utilization as the `mov al, xx` operation only takes 2 bytes.

Comment: So mov qword [rbp - 16], rax moves the NSString into rax?

Comment: It's the other way around. `mov qword [rbp - 16], rax` moves the value in `rax` into the stack memory. `rax` holds the value returned from the objc call which is a pointer to a NSString instance

Comment: so why is there a `mov rax, qword [ rbp - 16 ]`? wouldnt that be the opposite?

Comment: Yes, first it saves the return value to memory and then loads it back up into `rax`. The compiler is just basically translating operations it has identified without trying to optimize anything which is why it is so inefficient.